# .NET Core Appsettings in Console Vs. Web Templates

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 App in Visual Studio 2019 and the various `appsettings.*.json` files appear "nested" under the main `appsettings.json` file, like this:

[image]

In my .NET Core 3.1 Console App, however, the `appsettings.json` files appear flat, *not* nested:

[image]

The **.csproj** file for the web application is also extremely simple:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

whereas the **.csproj** file for the console application seems to explicitly mention the appsettings files:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="appsettings.QA.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

How can I get my `appsettings.json` files in the console application to appear "nested" like in the web application? Can anyone offer any additional insights as to how/why these **.csproj** files look different?

Comment: For the `.Production` and `.QA` JSON settings in the _.csproj_, try adding `<DependentUpon>appsettings.json</DependentUpon>` after the CopyToOutputDirectory tag.

Comment: Thanks @Leandro. That gave me what I wanted.

Comment: @Tom-Baxter, I'm curious how you created a simple json output in your bluemix video (re: To Do tasks)  leon.matthys@gmail.com